# How to design the generator in generative adversarial network (GAN)?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gan

I am new to GAN. And recently read a paper about how to implement GAN in recommender system [here](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2018/0511.pdf)

I have a question in the paper.

The `Eq (20)` in the paper should be the  discriminator function.

The generator should be the $G_{\phi}$ which is mentioned in the `Eq (21)` and `Eq (22)`. However, what is definition of $G_{\phi}$ here?

Thanks,

Comment: are you asking in general what is the generative part of a GAN, or are you asking what is the specific network architecture that was used by this paper for their generator?

Comment: Only for this paper, thanks

Comment: @JahKnows I read the paper many times and I can't find the definition of $G_\theta$. Do it have some common definition so the authors omits?